# PHP SoapClient::__construct uncustomized request

Tags: php, constructor, soap-client

I use PHP SoapClient to work with my JAVA application.

Here's a pseudo-code of my extended SoapClient class:

```
class MyClient extends SoapClient {

  public function __construct($url) {
    $params = Array (
        'login' => 'some_login',
        'password' => 'some_password',
        'trace' => true,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'connection_timeout' => 10,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
    );

    try {
      parent::__construct($url, $params);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
      /* some logging action */
    }
    catch(SoapFault $e) {
      /* some logging action */
    }
}
```

So I make a new object using my class:

```
$obj = new MyClient("http://location/file.wsdl");
```

and it sending a GET request to get xml structure in response:

```
GET /file.wsdl HTTP/1.0
Host: location
Authorization: Basic ....
```

A problem is that I can't use `SoapClient::__getLastRequest`, `SoapClient:: __getLastResponse`, `SoapClient::__getLastResponseHeaders` and `SoapClient::__setCookie`, even `SoapClient::_cookies` in constructor, because all of these functions are valid after `__call` or `__doRequest` only, but a constructor never fire `__doRequest`.

So I can't customize a constructor request to set and get cookies in result. Because of this my application session management doesn't work correct, because a constructor request fire a new session but I can't get jsessionid cookie in a response.

I've tried to search for `::__construct` source code to override it with my own cookie-supported code but nothing.

All of tips in the Internet to use CURL for SOAP requests based on overriding `__call` or `__doRequest` functions but a constructor doesnt use them.

Please, any ideas how can I extend a constructor with a custom request?

---

**UPDATE:**

I just used soapclient in non-WSDL mode which doesn't fetch a file in a constructor and doesn't send any uncustomized requests. Thanx for your tips, problem solved.

Comment: I don't really understand what is the issue. It appears you expect to have a `lastRequest` and `lastResponse` just by instantiating the soap client. Fetching the WSDL to get the list of available services **is not a request**.

Comment: I just need to get a HTTP response after `::__construct` to extract a session cookie. I expect to have at least `LastResponseHeaders`.

Comment: For large SOAP applications, it's actually a good idea to cache the WSDL file and most enterprise soap applications do that. The constructor for SoapClient does not necessarily touch the webserver that offers the actual services. If you need the cookie, you can create a handshake service that gives you that cookie. Or call any random service in the constructor.

Comment: Fetching WSDL should not start the session, it should be done by initial request to actual API. For example WSDL can be placed on other server (like cdn for static content only) and point actions to another, or just cached (not only on your client side, but also on any possible proxy in between). So once again, you should not rely on starting session by fetching WSDL.